# Is IPS threading compatible with NPT threading?

Tags: plumbing

I've attached two links to the fittings I'm looking to purchase online.  But I don't know if they will work together.

[Chrome Plated Brass Pipe Fitting, Coupling , 1/2" NPT Female](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0046A881S)

[image]

and

[Moen 116651 6-Inch Straight Shower Arm, Chrome](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000T89LSA)

[image]

Comment: The following table describe various thread standards:
http://www.onestopfire.com/threads.htm

Comment: If you can use a smaller pipe, something like this should work, http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0046A8F84/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?ie=UTF8&m=ATVPDKIKX0DER although that doesnt answer your question.

Comment: You would need to go to a nut and bolt shop for this one.. threads are a pain in the wrist.

Comment: @fubacrew I think finding a different pipe is the way to go.  The one you link to looks promising.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[According to the Googles](http://www.onestopfire.com/threads.htm), IPS is Iron Pipe Straight thread.  It's meant to seal on a washer-shaped gasket (like the threads the hose for your toilet or faucets attach to).  NPT is a tapered thread, designed to seal on the threads, which is why you put pipe tape on them - to lubricate them and help the threads deform and create a seal.

So, while having no personal experience, I would say no, they will not thread together.  I've been hunting around for adapters, but don't see anything.  Which is weird, because I'd think those arms would be designed to thread into a brass NPTF fitting in the wall/ceiling.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is perfectly correct regarding how IPS and NPT threads operate, and they are quite different in that respect.

But there are also some useful similarities. The actual thread specifications are very similar:

[image]

<sub>(Source: http://www.onestopfire.com/threads.htm)</sub>

IPS (also known as NPSH) is the left circled column, NPT is the right. You can see that the actual outside diameters are very close, and threads-per-inch (TPI) are *the same*.

Does this similarity mean you can get a liquid-tight seal screwing IPS and NPT fittings together? No, absolutely not. But it DOES mean that in some cases you can get a useful *mechanical* lock between the components (albeit a relatively less common scenario).

An example would be a faucet having NPT shanks which drop below the sink for water supply attachment. These can be secured to the sink using untapered **nuts**.